# Call lambda with other lambda result when its return type is void

Tags: c++, lambda, metaprogramming, c++17

The following function makes a lambda that calls the second callable with the first callable's result. If the first callable returns a tuple it will be applied to the second callable.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_tuple : std::false_type{};

template<typename... T>
struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type{};

template<typename S, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) pipeline(S&& source, T&& target)
{
    return [callables = std::tuple<S, T>(std::forward<S>(source), std::forward<T>(target))]
    (auto&&... args)
    {
        const auto&[source, target] = callables;

        using source_return = decltype(source(args...));

        if constexpr(is_tuple<source_return>::value)
        {
            return std::apply(target, source(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
        }
        else
        {
            return target(source(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
        }
    };
}
```

However this does not compile when the source callable returns void, since it will try to call target with incomplete type void, so I tried the following:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) pipeline(S&& source, T&& target)
{
    return [callables = std::tuple<S, T>(std::forward<S>(source), std::forward<T>(target))]
    (auto&&... args)
    {
        const auto&[source, target] = callables;

        using source_return = decltype(source(args...));

        if constexpr(is_tuple<source_return>::value)
        {
            return std::apply(target, source(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
        }
        else if constexpr(std::is_void_v<source_return>)
        {
            source(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            return target();
        }
        else
        {
            return target(source(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
        }
    };
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work somehow since it always takes the same as void branch, even when the source function cannot return void in any situation. I geuss there is something wrong with the decltype deducing the source_return. I tried to assign the result of source to a variable to decltype the that variable instead of decltype(source(args...)) but then it gives me the error that the variable is of incomplete type void in the cases it actually does return void, so I do have to check it before actually calling source.

Here is an example of pipeline usage that does not compile:

```
auto callable = pipeline([]{ return 10 },
                         [](size_t val){ return val * 10});

callable();
```

The reason it does not compile is because it takes the source_return is same as void branch for some reason. Anybody has any idea how I can figure out the return type of source when called with args... in a way that is more robust?

EDIT:

I got it to work by using a call_pipeline helper function. I still don't understand why this one would work and the other one doesn't though.

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_pipeline(const S& source, const T& target, Args&&... args)
{
    using source_return = decltype(source(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    if constexpr(std::is_void_v<source_return>)
    {
        source(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return target();
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr(is_tuple<source_return>::value)
        {
            return std::apply(target, source(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }
        else
        {
            return target(source(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }
    }
}

template<typename S, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) pipeline(S&& source_init, T&& target_init)
{
    return [callables = std::tuple<S, T>(std::forward<S>(source_init),
                                         std::forward<T>(target_init))]
    (auto&&... args)
    {
        const auto&[source, target] = callables;
        return call_pipeline(source, target, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: How does `is_tuple` look like?

Comment: [This looks weirder and weirder by the minute](https://godbolt.org/g/1mEGwo)

Comment: Added the is_tuple trait

Comment: Then you also need to show how you're using `pipeline`

Comment: Added a simple example of pipeline usage

Comment: Even if I define `using source_return = int;` I still throws on error on `return target();`. Very strange.

Comment: As a guess is a bug in lambda return type deduction.  I mean: https://godbolt.org/g/3RmJpw

Comment: Yeah I think its a bug too since the helper function does manage to deduce it properly...

Comment: Submitted [85149](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85149).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about isn't working your way but I propose the following alternative

```
template<typename S, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) pipeline(S&& source, T&& target)
{
    return [callables = std::tuple<S, T>(std::forward<S>(source),
                                         std::forward<T>(target))]
    (auto&&... args)
    {
        const auto&[source, target] = callables;

        auto tplr = [](auto s, auto && ... as)
        {
           using source_return
              = decltype(s(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...));
            if constexpr ( is_tuple<source_return>::value )
                return s(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...);
            else if constexpr ( std::is_void_v<source_return> )
            {
                s(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...);
                return std::make_tuple();
            }
            else
                return std::make_tuple(s(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...));
        }(source, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

        std::apply(target, tplr);
    };
}
```

The idea is ever made `target()` called through `std::apply` with a `std::tuple` (maybe empty) of arguments.